# UICollectionView container inside of UIScrollView breaks scrolling in ios 9.1

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout, uicontainerview, ios9.1

I have one large scrollView that contains a collectionView and a tableView. Neither the collection view and table view scroll independently. Both are resized based on their content so the user is just scrolling a long view within the scroll view.

[image]

This has always worked out fine until ios 9.1. Now any attempt by the user to pan within one of the collection container views fails to scroll the outer scroll view.

Can someone explain what has changed in ios 9.1 to make this setup no longer work?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was entirely related to this [issue](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout/issues/92) with LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout